# How does Kenshiro gets his shirts back in the manga?

Tags: fist-of-the-north-star

A typical scene if Hokuto no Ken is when Kenshiro is starting to fight his shirt is ripped due to the release of its energy, this happens, if not in all, in most episodes.

There's an scene in anime where he's seen fabricating them, but that scene was from a filler episode.

I think in the manga this is nowhere to be seen, although perhaps the author also answered to this on some SBS, or similar.

Has the author ever said something about that?

Comment: It would be very difficult to comment unless one has seen the question being asked in an interview before. Searches on Google only linked to the filler episode but no Manga links came up